# why need linker script and startup code?

Tags: gcc, embedded, startup, linker-scripts

I've read [this tutorial](http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/data-in-ram.html)

I could follow the guide and run the code. but I have questions.

1) Why do we need both load-address and run-time address. As I understand it is because we have put .data at flash too; so why we don't run app there, but need start-up code to copy it into RAM?

http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/c-startup.html

2) Why we need linker script and start-up code here. Can I not just build C source as below and run it with qemu?

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostdlib -o sum_array.elf sum_array.c
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Why do we need both load-address and run-time address.

While it is in most cases possible to run code from memory mapped ROM, often code will execute faster from RAM.  In some cases also there may be a much larger RAM that ROM and application code may compressed in ROM, so the executable code may not simply be copied from ROM also decompressed - allowing a much larger application than the available ROM.

In situations where the code is stored on non-memory mapped mass-storage media such as NAND flash, it cannot be executed directly in any case and must be loaded into RAM by some sort of bootloader.

> 2) Why we need linker script and start-up code here. Can I not just build C source as below and run it with qemu?

The linker script defines the memory layout of you target and application.  Since this tutorial is for bare-metal programming, there is no OS to handle that for you.  Similarly the start-up code is required to at least set an initial stack-pointer, initialise static data, and jump to main.  On an embedded system it is also necessary to initialise various hardware such as the PLL, memory controllers etc.

Answer (score 7):

Your first question was answered in the guide.

When you load a program on an operating system your .data section, basically non-zero globals, are loaded from the "binary" into the right offset in memory for you, so that when your program starts those memory locations that represent your variables have those values.

```
unsigned int x=5;
unsigned int y;
```

As a C programmer you write the above code and you expect x to be 5 when you first start using it yes?   Well, if are booting from flash, bare metal, you dont have an operating system to copy that value into ram for you, somebody has to do it.  Further all of the .data stuff has to be in flash, that number 5 has to be somewhere in flash so that it can be copied to ram.  So you need a flash address for it and a ram address for it.  Two addresses for the same thing.

And that begins to answer your second question, for every line of C code you write you assume things like for example that any function can call any other function.  You would like to be able to call functions yes?  And you would like to be able to have local variables, and you would like the variable x above to be 5 and you might assume that y will be zero, although, thankfully, compilers are starting to warn about that.  The startup code at a minimum for generic C sets up the stack pointer, which allows you to call other functions and have local variables and have functions more than one or two lines of code long, it zeros the .bss so that the y variable above is zero and it copies the value 5 over to ram so that x is ready to go when the code your entry point C function is run.

If you dont have an operating system then you have to have code to do this, and yes, there are many many many sandboxes and toolchains that are setup for various platforms that already have the startup and linker script so that you can just

```
gcc -O myprog.elf myprog.c
```

Now that doesnt mean you can make system calls without a...system...printf, fopen, etc.   But if you download one of these toolchains it does mean that you dont actually have to write the linker script nor the bootstrap.

But it is still valuable information, note that the startup code and linker script are required for operating system based programs too, it is just that native compilers for your operating system assume you are going to mostly write programs for that operating system, and as a result they provide a linker script and startup code in that toolchain.

Answer (score 2):

1) The .data section contains variables.  Variables are, well, variable -- they change at run time.  The variables need to be in RAM so that they can be easily changed at run time.  Flash, unlike RAM, is not easily changed at run time.  The flash contains the initial values of the variables in the .data section.  The startup code copies the .data section from flash to RAM to initialize the run-time variables in RAM.

2) Linker-script:  The object code created by your compiler has not been located into the microcontroller's memory map.  This is the job of the linker and that is why you need a linker script.  The linker script is input to the linker and provides some instructions on the location and extent of the system's memory.

Startup code:  Your C program that begins at `main` does not run in a vacuum but makes some assumptions about the environment.  For example, it assumes that the initialized variables are already initialized before `main` executes.  The startup code is necessary to put in place all the things that are assumed to be in place when `main` executes (i.e., the "run-time environment").  The stack pointer is another example of something that gets initialized in the startup code, before `main` executes.  And if you are using C++ then the constructors of static objects are called from the startup code, before `main` executes.